Jacobian of plane curve
I am trying to prove the following:
Let $C$ be a reduced singular curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that the lines of its Jacobian matrix are linearly dependent. Then I would like to prove that $C$ is the intersection of 3 lines meeting in a point.
If $C = V(F)$ where $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial in degree $d$, then, from the hypothesis we can assume that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \alpha \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+ \beta\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$. I tried to use this, together with Euler identity to prove that $F$ contains at least 3 lines, and from its reducibility it should be equal to these 3 lines, but the computations doesn't add up. Does someone have any suggestions?
Update: I was able to brute force the case when the curve has degree 3. So now is lacking an argument to why we can reduce it to the degree 3 case.
Thank in advance.
